# Find largest eigenvalue of specific nonnegative matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I look for the largest eigenvalue of the following matrix (or at least a small upper bound).
The only thing I know is that the eigenvalue is smaller than 1 and converges to $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2n+1})$ with growing n.

In general, it is very hard to compute the characteristic polynomial to calculate the eigenvalue and that's why I hope for an easier way.

Has anyone some ideas?

The dimension of the matrix is $n \times n$.
$A = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{n+1}}&  \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 &0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Is the dimension of the matrix $n \times n$, and should $a_{n-1, n}$ be $1/2$ instead of zero?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Instead of the zero I wanted to include $\vdots$but you are right that $a_{n-1,n}$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: This is equivalent to maximizing $(n + 1) x_1^2/(2 n + 1) + x_1 x_2 + \ldots + x_{n - 1} x_n$ over the sphere $\lVert x \rVert = 1$. But that doesn't seem to make things simpler.

Comment: $1-\frac{1}{2(n-1)(2n-1)}$ seems to be an upper bound on the largest eigenvalue (verified via testing for $1 \leq n \leq 10 000$ in MatLab). Now, only the proof is missing ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An asymptotic expansion for large $n$ can be obtained as follows. Expanding $A - \lambda I$ by the first row and expanding one of the resulting matrices by the first column gives
$$\det(A - \lambda I) =
\left( \frac {n + 1} {2 n + 1} - \lambda \right) \det \tilde A_{n - 1} -
 \frac 1 4 \det \tilde A_{n - 2},$$
where $\tilde A_n$ is a tridiagonal  Toeplitz matrix with $-\lambda$ on the main diagonal and $1/2$ on the two adjacent diagonals. The determinant of $\tilde A_n$ is $2^{-n} U_n(-\lambda)$, where $U_n$ is the Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind. Since $U_n(-\cos \theta) = (-1)^n \csc \theta \,\sin \,(n + 1) \theta$, $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0$ reduces to
$$\cot n \theta =
\left( \frac {2 n + 2} {2 n + 1} - \cos \theta \right) \csc \theta.$$
Taking $\theta = \alpha/n$ and expanding both sides of the equation into series, we obtain $\cot \alpha = 1/(2 \alpha) + O(1/n)$, determining $\alpha$. Then
$$\lambda_{\max} = \cos \theta \sim
1 -\frac {\alpha^2} {2 n^2},$$
where $\alpha$ is the smallest positive root of $\cot \alpha = 1/(2 \alpha)$. The next terms can be obtained in the same manner.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your help. This seems to be correct but I have a question. Why do you compute $U_n(\cos(\Delta))$? Because the largest eigenvalue of A seems to be related to a cosine term or is there a different mathematical evidence?

Comment: The change of variables is $\lambda = \cos \theta$, because we want to use the identity $U_n(-\cos x) = (-1)^n \csc x \,\sin \,(n + 1) x$. Then it's just some algebraic manipulations to get the equation for $\theta$. $\lambda$ close to one corresponds to $\theta$ close to zero.